# Fetch all variable values in vbscript using msscript control

Tags: variables, vbscript, msscriptcontrol

Is there any way to fetch all the variable values in the script at runtime.

Consider the following  vbscript code.

```
var1= 5
Var2= 6

For i=0 To 5
   Msgbox i
Next
```

How do i Implement it using msscript control that i should be able to retrieve all the variables at runtime?

I am looking to implement a debugger for vbscript can i have the list of all the variables at runtime like below.

```
var1=5
Var2=6
i=5
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are! Save the code below as VBScript file:

```
' VBS code variables to be fetched from
sVBScriptDebug = _
    "var1= 5" & vbCrLf & _
    "Var2= 6" & vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    "For i=0 To 5" & vbCrLf & _
    "   Msgbox i" & vbCrLf & _
    "Next"

' ScriptControl to be used for debug purposes
Set oScrCtlDebug = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
oScrCtlDebug.Language = "VBScript"
oScrCtlDebug.AddCode sVBScriptDebug
' Me object from debug script
Set oMeDebug = oScrCtlDebug.Eval("Me")

' ScriptControl for JScript utility function pushing all object's properties to array
Set oScrCtlUtil = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
oScrCtlUtil.Language = "JavaScript"
oScrCtlUtil.Eval("Enum=function(x){this.x=new Array();for (var i in x) {this.x[i]=i};return this.x}")
' Retrieve JScript this object
Set oJSGlobal = oScrCtlUtil.Eval("this")

' Cycle through all debug script Me object properties, that actually are fetched global scope variables
sRes = ""
For Each sVar In oJSGlobal.Enum(oMeDebug)
    sRes = sRes & sVar & "=" & oScrCtlDebug.Eval(sVar) & vbCrLf
Next
MsgBox sRes
```